# Nopcommerce change shipping rules code

Tags: shopping-cart, nopcommerce

I am using nopcommerce a open source shopping cart system. I want to change the shipping rules i.e. if any one buy a product of less than $1000 then he must pay a shipping charges of rupee $10 otherwise no shipping charges will apply. i want to do this through code. please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a new shipping rate computation method plugin. Please have a look at IShippingRateComputationMethod interface. Put all required logic into 'GetShippingOptions' method.

Answer (score 0):

Nopcommerce has provide a new plugin for shipping rule "**Shipping.Director**" where you can write your own Expression for shipping  you should try that one reference link 
http://www.noptools.com/

Comment: That was not provided by nopCommerce. That was a third party plugin.